# How to override background color in internal CSS with react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-big-calendar

Here is my code

```
eventStyleGetter(event, start, end, isSelected) {
      if (event.id == 39) {
            var style = {
                backgroundColor: '#409931',
                borderRadius: '0px',
                opacity: 0.8,
                color: 'red',
                border: '0px',
                display: 'block'
            };

        }

        return {
            style: style
        }

 }
```

I want to change the background color but it is overridden with another CSS style. How to override this background color with react js.

[image]

Comment: The `!important` flag in the `.today-appointments` class may be the one overriding you target style. Maybe remove the `!important`?

Comment: That important keyword comes automatically that's the issue. @molamk

Comment: Try `backgroundColor: '#409931 !important',`, that should override the other rule.

Comment: @ChrisG I already tried it but I would not work. Anyway thanks for the help (Y)

Comment: Yeah, react apparently doesn't support `!important` in style objects. I found this though: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-with-important-style

Comment: @ChrisG thank you. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than applying this as a `style`, dynamically apply a `className`, using the same `eventPropGetter` method. `className`s are appended, so any `className` that you apply to the event will be parsed *after* the default classes, and you can use `!important` in the class definition.

Comment: Side Note: `className`s, returned from your `eventPropGetter`, are expected to be a String, and not an Object, so if you ever have more than one they must be in a space delimited list (i.e. `className: 'custom-style1 blocked-event'`)